# google cloud pm2 start nodejs successfully but not accessible

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, pm2, vpc

I started node server successfully with pm2 but I couldn't access to my host.

[image: port]

I opened port on google cloud.

1. OS: Debian.
2. node version: v8.12.0
3. pm2 version: 3.2.2

[image: pm2]

I tried `pm2 kill` and restart but nothing happend. What am I wrong?

Comment: Which address is the server bound to (0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, localhost)? Is the server listening on port 3000? `netstat -l` lists ports in listening state.

Comment: 0.0.0.0/0 bound to, localhost listening port 3000. `netstat -l` show me result `tcp6       0      0 [::]:3000               [::]:*                  LISTEN`

Answer (score 0):

Take the following steps to remediate your connectivity issue:

1. Check to see what programs are running and what port(s) they are listening on. See if you can identify your program running:
   `sudo netstat -tnlp` If you see a `node` process, notice the port it is listening on. Does this match *3000*? If so, check to see what network address it is listening on: Does it show `0.0.0.0` or does it show `127.0.0.1`? If it shows `127.0.0.1` then your application is only listening on localhost and you need to modify it to listen on `0.0.0.0`.
2. Check the *local* firewall to see if you have allowed port *3000* by running `sudo iptables -nL`. If you do not see ANY rules period and see "policy ACCEPT" then you're ok. Otherwise, if you do not see TCP port 3000 then we need to add an allow/permit rule. To do so run `sudo ufw allow 3000`. If the `ufw` command is not found then you can run `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --jport 2195 -j ACCEPT` followed by `sudo /etc/init.d/iptables save`.
3. If you still cannot connect to your application please provide the output to the following commands:

   - `sudo iptables -nL`
   - `sudo netstat -tnlp`
   - `gcloud compute firewall-rules list` (if gcloud cli is installed, otherwise another screenshot of your firewall rules under your network settings in GCP console).

Comment: 1. `sudo netstat -tnlp` show me result `tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1005/node /var/loca`.
2. I run  `sudo ufw allow 3000` but it still not access to host
3. `gcloud compute firewall-rules list` show an ERROR: `- Insufficient Permission`

Answer (score 0):

I config nginx default as a proxy to nodejs server. And It still work!

```
 proxy_pass    http://localhost:3000;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check first with `curl http://localhost:3000`
2. Make sure you open your project firewall port 3000

https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list?project=xxxx

3. Run this SELINUX, I'm on centos7

   `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`

   `sudo setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs on`

   `sudo chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /home/admin/www`

   `sudo systemctl restart nginx`